# Double Sum to Product Derivation

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, summation, products

> The function after the double-sigma sign can be separated into the
> product of two terms, the first of which does not depend on $s$ and
> the second of which does not depend on $r$. [Source](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob06.pdf)

Is the derivation below correct? Begin with
$$\sum_{p} \sum_{q} f(p)f(q)$$

Move $f(p)$ outside since it is a constant with respect to $q$:
$$\sum_{p}  \left( f(p) \sum_{q} f(q) \right) $$

Move $\sum_{q} f(q)$ outside since it is a constant with respect to $p$:
$$\left( \sum_{q} f(q) \right)  \left( \sum_{p}f(p) \right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your derivation is correct.